# Rails 7 - link_to without underlying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5

**Background**

In my Rails 7 with Turbo and Bootstrap app I've got a table with few headers but only 3 of the 6 headers can be used as sorting. Data for that table comes from external API so to sort that data I need to pass the `sort` and `direction` params into the API client. Everything works well, passing params, retrieve data etc.

**Current implementation**

To make sorting happen I'm using `link_to` where I redirect users to the same path but passing extra params of `column` and `direction`. Example for `status` header below.

`view`

```
<%= link_to 'Status', column: 'status', direction: 'desc' %>
```

`controller`

```
  def sort_params
    {
      sort_by: params[:column],
      direction: params[:direction],
    }.compact_blank!
  end
```

**Issue**

Everything works well but the styling of `link_to` is ugly. Columns that are used for sorting have typical `link_to` styling with this ugly underlying:

[image]

How to get rid of that underlying and have the same styling as e.g. it is in `Order Id` or `Payment Method` headers?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `text-decoration: none;` CSS instruction

Comment: I've made `<%= link_to 'Status', column: 'status', direction: 'desc', class: 'sort' %>` and placed `.sort {
  text-decoration: none;
}` inside `styles.scss` but nothing changed.

Comment: @tajfun_88 not sure I understand your comment [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s6bwofxd/)

Comment: @engineersmnky So why on earth it doesn't work on my app?